# Plugins Page - "Page disabled by the administrator"

Tags: permissions

I've encountered an issue on a site I'm looking after.

The 'admin' account no longer has access to the plugins page, if I try and manually type in the URL to the page, I get the following error:

"Page disabled by the administrator"

Any idea what could be causing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually just fixed it myself.

The problem was as follows:

I had changed the username of the admin account to 'new-admin'. What I had missed when making this change was to update the 'wp_sitemeta' table in the database. meta_id 8 (site_admins) still had the old admin name set. Once I updated this, the plugins menu reappeared!